# WSO2 ESB how get value of JMSReplyTo of imcoming message

Tags: wso2-esb

Request messages come in WSO3 ESB through the ActiveMQ.
Jms header "JMSReplyTo" of messages is set to a certain value.
I need to get this value in ESB sequence.
I try use get-property("ReplyTo"), but get no result.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with get-property('transport','JMSReplyTo')